# Share spring beans in teracotta

Tags: java, spring, terracotta

Wondering why we need to share spring beans in case if there are no static data inside?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to share the `ApplicationContext` - it holds the bean instances and definitions needed. The beans themselves aren't useful (from dependency-injection perspective) without their context.